# loop and in admin header problem

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, admin

I have a WP_Query loop running in a function that's attached to the 'admin_enqueue_scripts' hook

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'rs_get_scripts'); 
function rs_get_scripts() {
    //enqueue js file
    ...

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
    $query = new WP_Query($args);                      
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        /* bug occurs no matter what code is in here */
        //get data about each post
        ...

    endwhile;endif;wp_reset_query();

    //localize the data I got from each events post type into js file
     ...

}
```

What is happening is that running this loop at the time of 'admin_enqueue_scripts' hook seems to screw up the admin. 
The bug is that when I try to create a new post, page or any other Custom Post Type, Wordpress always redicrects me to to create a post of the post type I am querying in the loop above. In this case it's "events". I tried changing the loop to query_posts and get_posts but with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Move the query part to a separate function that returns the data you need:

```
function rs_get_scripts_data(){
    $array = array();
    // query + add stuff to array
    return $array;
}
```

and use it with wp_localize_script like:

```
$array = rs_get_scripts_data();
$myscript_vars = array(
    'array'  => $array
);
wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'myscript', $myscript_vars );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help diggy! I just found another question that  answers this so it's a dupe :/

Comment: Here's the question that answers this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21882/using-the-loop-inside-admin